# why am i getting a SIGTRAP in gdb while debugging Ruby C extension?

Tags: c, ruby

I want to use rb_p() to aid in debugging a ruby C extension, but everytime i use it i get a SIGTRAP in gdb!

here's an example:

(gdb) p user_defaults

$3 = 137559900

(gdb) call rb_p(user_defaults)

{:fill=>true, :texture=>#}

(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
is_a_hash (try_hash=137560420) at utils.c:65
(gdb)

why does this happen? how can i stop it happening??

Answer (score 1):

SIGTRAP is caused by a breakpoint exception, specifically by the `int3` instruction on x86 (interrupt 3).  Your code is probably executing an `int3`.  Take a look where gdb is telling you -- at `utils.c` line 65 in the `is_a_hash()` function.  If you don't have access to the source code, you can at least get the disassembly from gdb by typing

```
disas try_hash
```

at the gdb prompt.

Comment: what does this exception mean exactly? what's the purpose of it? do you hazard a guess why the code is executing that instruction?